# CUDA Broken Float Math on Kepler/Fermi Arch

Tags: cuda

I have a program that does a lot of single precision math.  It produces correct results if I specify 1.0 architecture but is broken for 2.X and 3.X architectures.  What would cause this?

Included below:
Very long code sample.
Compile command and good output.
Compile command and bad output.

If I run the same routing in the CPU using gcc, I get results that match the 1.0 architecture.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>

/* 
 * svdcomp - SVD decomposition routine. 
 * Takes an mxn matrix a and decomposes it into udv, where u,v are
 * left and right orthogonal transformation matrices, and d is a 
 * diagonal matrix of singular values.
 *
 * This routine is adapted from svdecomp.c in XLISP-STAT 2.1 which is 
 * code from Numerical Recipes adapted by Luke Tierney and David Betz.
 * Originally from: "Numerical Recipes in C: The Art of Scientific Computing",
 * Press, Flannery, Teukolosky, Vetterling. 1992.
 *
 * Input to dsvd is as follows:
 *   a = mxn matrix to be decomposed, gets overwritten with u
 *   m = row dimension of a
 *   n = column dimension of a
 *   w = returns the vector of singular values of a
 *   v = returns the right orthogonal transformation matrix
*/

#define SIGN(a, b) ((b) >= 0.0f ? fabsf(a) : -fabsf(a))
#define MIN(x,y) ( (x) < (y) ? (x) : (y) )
#define MAX(x,y) ((x)>(y)?(x):(y))

#define PERR(call) \
  if (call) {\
   fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d Error [%s] on "#call"\n", __FILE__, __LINE__,\
      cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));\
   exit(1);\
  }
#define ERRCHECK \
  if (cudaPeekAtLastError()) { \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d Error [%s]\n", __FILE__, __LINE__,\
       cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));\
    exit(1);\
  }

__device__ int 
svd(float *a, int m, int n, float *w, float *v, int skip_u)
{
    int flag, i, its, j, jj, k, l, nm;
    float c, f, h, s, x, y, z;
    float anorm = 0.0f, g = 0.0f, scale = 0.0f;

    float rv1[3];

    /* Householder reduction to bidiagonal form */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        /* left-hand reduction */
        l = i + 1;
        rv1[i] = scale * g;
        g = s = scale = 0.0f;
        if (i < m) 
        {
            for (k = i; k < m; k++) 
                scale += fabsf(a[k*n+i]);
            if (scale) 
            {
                for (k = i; k < m; k++) 
                {
                    a[k*n+i] /= scale;
                    s += powf(a[k*n+i], 2);
                }
                f = a[i*n+i];
                g = -SIGN(sqrtf(s), f);
                h = f * g - s;
                a[i*n+i] = f - g;
                if (i != n - 1) 
                {
                    for (j = l; j < n; j++) 
                    {
                        for (s = 0.0f, k = i; k < m; k++) 
                            s += a[k*n+i] * a[k*n+j];
                        f = s / h;
                        for (k = i; k < m; k++) 
                            a[k*n+j] += f * a[k*n+i];
                    }
                }
                for (k = i; k < m; k++) 
                    a[k*n+i] *= scale;
            }
        }
        w[i] = scale * g;

        /* right-hand reduction */
        g = s = scale = 0.0f;
        if (i < m && i != n - 1) 
        {
            for (k = l; k < n; k++) 
                scale += fabsf(a[i*n+k]);
            if (scale) 
            {
                for (k = l; k < n; k++) 
                {
                    a[i*n+k] /= scale;
                    s += powf(a[i*n+k], 2);
                }
                f = a[i*n+l];
                g = -SIGN(sqrtf(s), f);
                h = f * g - s;
                a[i*n+l] = f - g;
                for (k = l; k < n; k++) 
                    rv1[k] = a[i*n+k] / h;
                if (i != m - 1) 
                {
                    for (j = l; j < m; j++) 
                    {
                        for (s = 0.0f, k = l; k < n; k++) 
                            s += a[j*n+k] * a[i*n+k];
                        for (k = l; k < n; k++) 
                            a[j*n+k] += s * rv1[k];
                    }
                }
                for (k = l; k < n; k++) 
                    a[i*n+k] *= scale;
            }
        }
        anorm = MAX(anorm, fabsf(w[i]) + fabsf(rv1[i]));
    }

    /* accumulate the right-hand transformation */
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        if (i < n - 1) 
        {
            if (g) 
            {
                for (j = l; j < n; j++)
                    v[j*n+i] = (a[i*n+j] / a[i*n+l]) / g;
                    /* float division to avoid underflow */
                for (j = l; j < n; j++) 
                {
                    for (s = 0.0f, k = l; k < n; k++) 
                        s += a[i*n+k] * v[k*n+j];
                    for (k = l; k < n; k++) 
                        v[k*n+j] += s * v[k*n+i];
                }
            }
            for (j = l; j < n; j++) 
                v[i*n+j] = v[j*n+i] = 0.0f;
        }
        v[i*n+i] = 1.0f;
        g = rv1[i];
        l = i;
    }

    /* accumulate the left-hand transformation */
    if (!skip_u) {
        for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            l = i + 1;
            g = w[i];
            if (i < n - 1) 
                for (j = l; j < n; j++) 
                    a[i*n+j] = 0.0f;
            if (g) 
            {
                g = 1.0f / g;
                if (i != n - 1) 
                {
                    for (j = l; j < n; j++) 
                    {
                        for (s = 0.0f, k = l; k < m; k++) 
                            s += a[k*n+i] * a[k*n+j];
                        f = (s / a[i*n+i]) * g;
                        for (k = i; k < m; k++) 
                            a[k*n+j] += f * a[k*n+i];
                    }
                }
                for (j = i; j < m; j++) 
                    a[j*n+i] = a[j*n+i]*g;
            }
            else 
            {
                for (j = i; j < m; j++) 
                    a[j*n+i] = 0.0f;
            }
            ++a[i*n+i];
        }
    }

    /* diagonalize the bidiagonal form */
    for (k = n - 1; k >= 0; k--) 
    {                             /* loop over singular values */
        for (its = 0; its < 30; its++) 
        {                         /* loop over allowed iterations */
            flag = 1;
            for (l = k; l >= 0; l--) 
            {                     /* test for splitting */
                nm = l - 1;
                if (fabsf(rv1[l]) + anorm == anorm) 
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                }
                if (fabsf(w[nm]) + anorm == anorm) 
                    break;
            }
            if (flag) 
            {
                c = 0.0f;
                s = 1.0f;
                for (i = l; i <= k; i++) 
                {
                    f = s * rv1[i];
                    if (fabsf(f) + anorm != anorm) 
                    {
                        g = w[i];
                        h = hypotf(f, g);
                        w[i] = h; 
                        h = 1.0f / h;
                        c = g * h;
                        s = (- f * h);
                        if (!skip_u) {
                            for (j = 0; j < m; j++) 
                            {
                                y = a[j*n+nm];
                                z = a[j*n+i];
                                a[j*n+nm] = y * c + z * s;
                                a[j*n+i] = z * c - y * s;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            z = w[k];
            if (l == k) 
            {                  /* convergence */
                if (z < 0.0f) 
                {              /* make singular value nonnegative */
                    w[k] = -z;
                    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) 
                        v[j*n+k] = -v[j*n+k];
                }
                break;
            }
            if (its >= 30) {
            }

            /* shift from bottom 2 x 2 minor */
            x = w[l];
            nm = k - 1;
            y = w[nm];
            g = rv1[nm];
            h = rv1[k];
            f = ((y - z) * (y + z) + (g - h) * (g + h)) / (2.0f * h * y);
            g = hypotf(f, 1.0f);
            f = ((x - z) * (x + z) + h * ((y / (f + SIGN(g, f))) - h)) / x;

            /* next QR transformation */
            c = s = 1.0f;
            for (j = l; j <= nm; j++) 
            {
                i = j + 1;
                g = rv1[i];
                y = w[i];
                h = s * g;
                g = c * g;
                z = hypotf(f, h);
                rv1[j] = z;
                c = f / z;
                s = h / z;
                f = x * c + g * s;
                g = g * c - x * s;
                h = y * s;
                y = y * c;
                for (jj = 0; jj < n; jj++) 
                {
                    x = v[jj*n+j];
                    z = v[jj*n+i];
                    v[jj*n+j] = x * c + z * s;
                    v[jj*n+i] = z * c - x * s;
                }
                z = hypotf(f, h);
                w[j] = z;
                if (z) 
                {
                    z = 1.0f / z;
                    c = f * z;
                    s = h * z;
                }
                f = (c * g) + (s * y);
                x = (c * y) - (s * g);
                if (!skip_u) {
                    for (jj = 0; jj < m; jj++) 
                    {
                        y = a[jj*n+j];
                        z = a[jj*n+i];
                        a[jj*n+j] = y * c + z * s;
                        a[jj*n+i] = z * c - y * s;
                    }
                }
            }
            rv1[l] = 0.0f;
            rv1[k] = f;
            w[k] = x;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}

__global__ void
svd_kernel(float *v)
{
    float a[9], w[3];

    a[0] = 8.0f;
    a[1] = 3.0f;
    a[2] = 7.0f;

    a[3] = 7.0f;
    a[4] = 9.0f;
    a[5] = 1.0f;

    a[6] = 3.0f;
    a[7] = 7.0f;
    a[8] = 2.0f;

    svd(a, 3, 3, w, v, 1);
}

int main()
{
  int i, j;
  float *v_d, v[9];

  PERR(cudaMalloc(&v_d, 9*sizeof(float)));
  svd_kernel<<<1,1>>>(v_d);
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  ERRCHECK;
  PERR(cudaMemcpy(v, v_d, 9*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

  for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      printf("%6.3f\t", v[i*3+j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

**Correct Results:**

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_10 -o svd svd.cu
$ ./svd
-0.657  -0.685   0.314  
-0.668   0.337  -0.664  
-0.349   0.646   0.679
```

**Broken Results:**

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -o svd svd.cu
$ ./svd 
-0.661  -0.660   0.356  
-0.642   0.253  -0.724  
 0.019   0.460   0.888
```

Comment: which CUDA version are you using?  I was able to reproduce your results on CUDA 5.5 but not on CUDA 6.0

Comment: CUDA version 5.5.  You see correct results for both cases with CUDA 6?  I am downloading it now.

Comment: Yes, with CUDA 5.5 I see the results you have posted.  With CUDA 6 I see the "Correct Results" whether I compile with `sm_10` or `sm_20`.  I tried fiddling with various [nvcc floating point compile switches](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-cuda-compilation) but didn't have any luck there narrowing down the behavior issue on cuda 5.5

Comment: I'm not sure if moving up to CUA 6.0 has already fixed this for you, but I would be concerned that lines in your code such as: **bold** '                a[i*n+l] = f - g;
                for (k = l; k < n; k++) 
                    rv1[k] = a[i*n+k] / h;'
may not be doing what you expect.  Namely that the write to a[] in global memory likely wouldn't have been transacted by the time you go to read that same address from global memory a few lines later.  Maybe the 6.0 compiler can detect this situation and force the global memory write to finish.  You could try declaring a[] to be volatile...

Comment: @MorbidFuzzball the entire application is a single thread (even on the GPU).  From the standpoint of a single thread, there's no possibility for a write to `a[]` to not be reflected in a read from the same location, some time later. Even if that write has not percolated all the way out to global memory (e.g. it is in L1 or L2 cache) the subsequent read will pick up the most recently modified value.  It does not bypass the cache, and then go to global memory and get a stale value. I'm not sure what you're getting at, but many aspects of language support would be broken if that were not the case

Comment: Switching to CUDA 6.0 solves the problem for now.  Why it is a problem is a curiosity that I hope to get back to later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that CUDA 6 fixes the issue.